# Why setup.exe is not showing the ARPCOMMENTS & WIXUIBanner.bmp but the setup.msi is showing this stuff?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have Setup.Bootstrapper Project to output a Setup.exe and the Setup project to give setup.msi output. But the problem is why my setup.exe is not showing the ARPCOMMENTS and also not showing the Banner.bmp file on running setup. on the other hand Setup.msi is working fine.

The Bundle code that I am using for Setup.Bootstrapper( Bundle.wxs) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
   <Bundle Name="ABC" Version="3.0.0.0" Manufacturer="XYZ, Inc." UpgradeCode="1EB9EC76-9E5F-4471-B522-314A62518A80">
      <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
         <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="License.rtf" SuppressOptionsUI="yes" />
      </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
      <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40ClientWeb" />
        <MsiPackage Compressed="yes" SourceFile="Setup.msi" Vital="yes" />
       </Chain>
      </Bundle>
  </Wix>
```

And the Setup Project using the Banner.bmp & ARP status is:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="License.rtf" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Bitmaps/Banner.bmp" />
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="ABC.exe" />
<Property Id="ARPCONTACT" Value="XYZ, Inc." />
<Property Id="ARPURLINFOABOUT" Value="http://www.xyz.com/" />
<Property Id="ARPCOMMENTS" Value="abc" />
```

any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundles don't use those. You can set bundle properties via attributes in the Bundle element. You can set WixStandardBootstrapperApplication properties with the bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication element's attributes. Not all are available in both bundles and packages.